# Find all possible combinations of two characters of an N length

Tags: python

I have two characters, for example:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
```

And I need to find all possible combinations of those two characters that will make a string of length N. For example, if `N = 3`:

```
combinations = ['aab', 'aba', 'baa', 'abb', 'bab', 'bba', 'aaa', 'bbb']
```

Is there a function in some module for this?

Comment: The word you're looking for is cross product. Combinations are a different thing. And yes there is, in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), but it might be beneficial to implement it yourself, especially if this is for a class assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you want here:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> N = 3
>>> lst = [a, b]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in product(lst, repeat = N)]
['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

Which can also be written with a triple nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [x + y + z for x in lst for y in lst for z in lst]
['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```